# Queue Length really affect Latency in DCTCP?

Tags: networking, tcp, queue, switch-statement, congestion-control

DCTCP is a variant of TCP for Data Center environment. [The source is here](http://simula.stanford.edu/~alizade/Site/DCTCP.html)

DCTCP using ECN feature in commodity switch to limit queue length of buffer in switch around the threshold K. Doing so, packet loss is rarely happen because K is much smaller than buffer's capacity so buffer isn't almost full.

DCTCP achieve low latency for small-flows while maintaining high throughput for big-flow. The reason is when queue length exceeds threshold K, a notification of congestion will be feedback to sender. At sender, a value for probability of congestion is computed over time, so sender will decrease sending rate correspondingly to the extent of congestion.

DCTCP states that small queue length will decrease the latency or the transmission time of flows. I doubted that. Because unless packet loss leading to re-transmission and so high latency. In DCTCP, packet loss rarely happens.

- Small queue at switch forces senders to decrease sending rates so force packets to queue in TX buffer of senders.
- Bigger queue at switch make senders have higher sending rates and packets instead queue in TX buffer of senders, it now queue in buffer of switch.

So I think that delay in both small and big queue is still the same.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

The buffer in the switch does not increase the capacity of the network, it only helps to not loose too much packets if you have a traffic burst. But, TCP can deal with packet loss by sending slower, which is exactly what it needs to do in case the network capacity is reached.

If you continuously run the network at the limit, the queue of the switch will be full or nearly full all the time, so you still loose packets if the queue is full. But, you also increase the latency, because the packet needs some time to get from the end of the queue where it arrived to the beginning where it will be forwarded. This latency again causes the TCP stack to react slower to congestion, which again increases congestion, packet loss etc.

So the ideal switch behaves like a network cable, e.g. does not have any buffer at all.
You might read more about the problems caused by large buffers by searching for "bufferbloat", e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat.

And when in doubt benchmark yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on queue occupancy. DCTCP aims to maintain small queue occupancy, because the authors think that queueing delay is the reason of long latency.

So, it does not matter how maximum size of queue is. In 16Mb of maximum queue size or just 32kb of maximum queue size, if we can maintain queue occupancy always around 8kb or something small size, queueing delay will be the same.

Read a paper, HULL from NSDI 2012, of M. Alizadeh who is the first author of DCTCP. HULL also aims to maintain short queue occupancy.

What they talk about small buffer is, because trends of data center switches shift from 'store and forward' buffer to 'cut-through' buffer. Just google it, and you can find some documents from CISCO or somewhere related webpages.